# How to map passing objects by value in the IDL file for Djinni

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, djinni

I'm trying to generate the wrapping classes for an existing c++ Library (with source code) to be used in ObjectiveC, I need to know how to write the idl interface for the methods that takes the same class as an argument 
for example:

In C++ header file for BigNumber class :

```
BigNumber add(BigNumber other);
```

I tried to write the same interface as an input to method:
bignumber.djinni

```
bignumberinterface =
    interface +c {
            static create(number: string): bignumberinterface;
        add(other: bignumberinterface): bignumberinterface;
    }:
```

But this generates the headers with the BigNumber as an input pointer.
So I got the error that :
Parameter type 'BigNumber' is an abstract class

Comment: Please check out djinni's documentation:
https://github.com/dropbox/djinni#modularization-and-library-support . The paragraph starts with: These files can be created by hand as long as you follow the required format. This allows you to support types not generated by Djinni.